# How to display extended ASCII characters, e.g., the standard degree symbol, DEC 167, on the Serial Monitor [not LCD]?

Tags: arduino-ide

I spent an afternoon researching this, and read a lot of material, but with no successful results.  [I really thought this would be a trivial task.]

Is this problem Windows, or WIN10, specific, as the extended characters all seem non-displayable? Regardless, is there a solution?

Comment: in extended ascii, degree '°' is DEC 248 per  http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/   DEC 167 looks a lot like a degree sign, but it is a 'masculine ordinal indicator'   see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_indicator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Arduino serial monitor uses UTF-8, per the discussion at http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=172814.0 --

For the U+00B0 degree symbol, you'd send the bytes UTF8 `0xC2 0xB0` like this:

```
Serial.print("°");
```